# how to calculate date difference

Tags: date, datetime, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

my data

```
column1        column2
    1-Sep-11     31-Aug-12
    1-May-12    30-Apr-14
    1-Mar-09    28-Feb-14
    1-Apr-13    31-Mar-14
    1-Apr-10    31-Mar-13
```

i want how many years difference between column1 and column2

out put like

```
column1        column2
    1-Sep-11     31-Aug-12      1
    1-May-12    30-Apr-14       2
    1-Mar-09    28-Feb-14      5
    1-Apr-13    31-Mar-14      1
    1-Apr-10    31-Mar-13      3
```

please let me know

Comment: Coming from 12/31/13 to 1/1/14 - would this be considered 1 year or 0?

Comment: i removed the Excel tag - as you're clearly searching for a LibreCalc solution - both pnut's and my solution work well under Excel.

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
=YEAR(B1)-YEAR(A1)
```

Comment: this is libre office calc

Answer (score 0):

Excel solution:

If you only want the difference between the years, i.e. coming from 31-Dec-13 to 1-Jan-14 should result in 1 year, use pnut's formula `=YEAR(B1)-YEAR(A1)`.

If you're interested in the real underlying duration, i.e. 1-Apr-13 to 31-Mar-14 would be 0 years, use this formula: `=INT((B1-A1)/365)`!

Comment: In Excel? Does A1 and B1 contain a date?

Comment: @pnuts: you're right, i actually entered this row wrongly into my example file. I guess the right formula depends on the OPs intent - see my other comment above...

Answer (score 0):

select to_date(Column1,'DD-MON-YYYY')- to_date(Column2,'DD-MON-YYYY') from Table;